# How to block a website programatically using DotNet

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to block a website programatically using DotNet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420931/how-to-block-a-website-programatically-using-dotnet)

HAI 
I am developing a software to run on the server and block the websites on the client systems using the client system name. My application is if I block **www.google.com**,entire website should be blocked i.e if user types **www.google.co.in**,it should not show the webpage of google.I have to block not a single url by editing c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts but the whole website.Thanking u
Chaithu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered to solve this via firewall rules instead? That would seem more natural to me... An .NET application seems not to be the appropriate technology to implement a web filter. Just for my own curiousity:

why do you wan't to block sites?

K

Answer (score 2):

1. Create simple http proxy solutions with exclusion list (or look for ready to use solution)
2. Restrict internet access to access only using Your proxy